# Suppose that $f(z) = u(x,y) + iv(x,y)$ is a holomorphic function and that $2u(x,y) + v(x,y) = 5$, for all $z=x+iy$ in $C$, show that $f$ is constant.

Tags: complex-analysis, complex-numbers

Any hints on where to start? I'm stuck.

I understand that is suffices to show that $f'(z) = 0$

In order to do that I must find what $u$ and $v$ in terms of $x$ and $y$ first, can you point me in the direction of how to do so?

Answer (score 1):

$2v_y+v_x=0$ and $-2v_x+v_y=0$ by Cauchy-Riemann equation so
$$
2v_y=-v_x=-\frac{v_y}{2}
$$

thus $5v_y=0$, so $v_y=0$ so again by Cauchy-Riemann we have $u_x=v_y=0$, by first equation we have $v_x=0$ so $-u_y=v_x=0$ and $u,v$ are constant's functions, in particular $f$.

Comment: Where is $u$? as you seem to only use $v$. I assume it's a spelling error, but it's really hard to understand this way.

Comment: I just use your equation+Cauchy-Riemann to isolate the partial derivatives of $v$, try derivative your equation, use Cauchy-Riemann and you will see.